# Dataframe stores duplicate header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that shows the files by size, but when I try to store the results in a dataframe, I get every result in a line with an index=0 the code of the function is:

```
def show_folders_by_size(r):
    size = 0
    calcul_size=[]
    path=[]
    for ele in os.scandir(r):
     size+=os.path.getsize(ele)
    size=size//1048576
    calcul_size.append(str(size)+" Mb")
    path.append(r)
    e = {'chemin du dossier' : path, 'taille par Mb' : size}
    df_dev_size = pd.DataFrame(e)
    print(path,calcul_size)
```

In the main:

```
months = time.time()-(3*2628000)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
for dir in dirs:
if ("back" in dir):
        path_back=os.path.join(root,dir)
        remove_files_by_modification_time(path_back)    
    elif ("dev" in dir):
        path_dev=os.path.join(root,dir)
        show_folders_by_size(path_dev)
```

This is the result I get:

```
['C:\\Users\\mbarrech\\Desktop\\dossier_test\\dev'] ['360 Mb']
['C:\\Users\\mbarrech\\Desktop\\dossier_test\\back_up\\dev'] ['360 Mb']
['C:\\Users\\mbarrech\\Desktop\\dossier_test\\dev\\back\\dev'] ['0 Mb']
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: based on your above - result what are you expecting? that will be really helpful and a complete [mcve] also you unindent your forloop after getting the size, is that intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that you need to create a Dataframe for every iteration. Store the results in an array and turn them into a single Dataframe afterwards like so :

```
results = []
def show_folders_by_size(r):
    // ... your function logic 
    results.append(dict(path=path, size=size))
```

And once your function is done running :

```
resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(resultsDf)
```

Cheers

Comment: it works but i get a result like :
 path  size
0  C:/Users/mbarrech/Desktop/dossier_test\dev   360
                                                path  size
0         C:/Users/mbarrech/Desktop/dossier_test\dev   360
1  C:/Users/mbarrech/Desktop/dossier_test\back_up...   360
                                                path  size
0         C:/Users/mbarrech/Desktop/dossier_test\dev   360
1  C:/Users/mbarrech/Desktop/dossier_test\back_up...   360
2  C:/Users/mbarrech/Desktop/dossier_test\dev\bac...     0
​
that's the problem that is making me go nuts

Comment: Let's be clear. In which format do you want your results to appear ?

Comment: the idea was to store them in a datafram and then send them to a xlsx or csv file

Comment: Try resultsDf.to_excel('output.xlsx') or ...to_csv() to see what it looks like ?